Convergence in Lp of bounded sequence is preserved under measure absolutely continuous?
Let $\mu$ and $\pi$ be probability measures such that $\mu<<\pi$. If $(f_n)$ is equibounded and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(d\pi)$, can I conclude that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(d\mu)$ ?

Hard to understand what you are asking. Can you use some symbols to say what exactly you want?

You’re right. I modify the question

Yes, you can. Use subsequences which converge almost surely and then use Bounded Convergence Theorem.

As $\mu<<\pi$, let $g$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\pi}$
Now let $f_{n_{k}}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $f_{n}$. As $f_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{L^{p}(\pi)}f$, there exists a further subsequence such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}f$ wrt $\pi$.
Then $$\int|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\,d\mu=\int |f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\cdot g\,d\pi$$
Now $|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\cdot g\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$,  and $|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\cdot g\leq M\cdot g$ for some $M>0$ (as $f_{n}$ is equibounded) . And $M\cdot g\in L^{1}(\pi)$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem tells you that
$$\int|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\,d\mu=\int |f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|^{p}\cdot g\,d\pi\xrightarrow{l\to\infty} 0$$
Thus $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{L^{p}(\mu)}f$. So, for any arbitrary subsequence $f_{n_{k}}$, there exists a further subsequence such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{L^{p}(\mu)}f$.
This is enough to show that $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{p}(\mu)}f$.
Note that Equiboundedness was important. In general $f\in L^{1}(\pi)$ need not imply $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$. See here where I have used $\mu$ and $\pi$ to be Exponential$(1/2)$ and Exponential$(1)$ distributions.
